# Identify row index of specific row within dataset by reference to the principal key

Tags: mysql

I have a table "documents", with an id column, which is the principal key. The table has numerous other fields and users can view the table sorted by reference to many of these fields. The table data is displayed within a virtual tree control which requests only the data it requires for the current client area of the tree.

Say my document table had the following structure and data (it doesn't, but the simple eg below is hopefully suffucient to illustrate)

```
id      description         date_of_doc
----------------------------------
 1      Doc 1               10/05/1987  
 2      Doc 2               11/06/1988  
 3      Doc 3               12/07/1989  
 4      Doc 4               13/08/1990  
 5      Doc 5               14/09/1991  
 6      Doc 6               15/10/1992
```

My virtual control loads the date in id order is as per the default table order.

However, the control allows you to click on headers which are called "description" and "date_of_doc". Clicking on these headers changes the order in which the data is displayed in the control. Click the same header twice and it will sort descending. I issue a new query to get the data with an "ORDER BY" command depending on what header has been clicked.

So if I am sorting by date_of_doc and it is descending then the new position of id 2 is in fact 5. Having sorted my user then clicks on the "Find by ID" link to find the document with the id "2". I now need to take him to the correct node within my tree control to find this document. From the simple dataset above we can work out that the new index of this position within the tree is 5. But how do I do that with a query taking into account the Order by clause.

Currently I am selecting the id field for every row in the table using the same Order by and then iterating through the query result until I can match the document id with the id requested by the user. There is nothing wrong with this query in the sense that it gets me the correct position, it just strikes me as grossly inefficient especially as I need to work with large tables.

What I am looking for is a query which is something like

> SELECT row_num FROM documents WHERE id=12345 ORDER BY date_of_doc

Comment: please post some sample data and expected output and what is wrong with the query you have .... otherwise hard to visualize whats happening

Comment: Edited original post. Hopefully explains better.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the control allows you to click on headers which are called
>   "description" and "date_of_doc". Clicking on these headers changes the
>   order in which the data is displayed in the control. Click the same
>   header twice and it will sort descending. I issue a new query to get
>   the data with an "ORDER BY" command depending on what header has been
>   clicked.

This is not very efficient as it needlessly hits the DB everytime someone tries to sort columns. You can retrieve data once per usersession and either cache the data on the Web Servers Memory and sort it in memory. Or use some client side sorting techniques using many javascript libraries ... Iam not an expert on these techniques but you should be able to find help on this topic as it is a very common scenario. Also you haven't mentioned what technology stack you are using to build your web app. C# asp.net, java , php, etc ...

So assuming that we are sorting in memory the only other call to the db would be to fetch the document for the particular requested document.

That said for your immediate need to avoid iterating rows to find 
To do that you can write a Stored procedure that takes the DocID and returns the recordset like so ( just pseudocode may need to tweak it for your actual scenario ) :

```
Create GetDocDetailsByID
(
  @id int
)
Begin

select id, description, date, ....
from yourtablename
where id = @id 

End
```

You should have that doc id in your application at run time when the user performs a button click or hits a hyperlink. Call the above SP with that ID. this part is platform specific. So let me know what is your front end platform and we can see if that needs tweaking.

Comment: The application is written using Delphi. The documents table may well contain millions of records. Rather than load the whole thing into memory (which I believed would be somewhat network intensive) I am only requesting sufficient data to populate the tree control and refreshing the display when the user scrolls etc. This seems to work well and efficiently with the one exception being the problem identified in the original post. That's why I need a mysql query which will give me the position within the data set of a specific row sorted in accordance with the specified order by.